# Infopath Get more then one user by User Picker

Tags: infopath, user-controls

How Could I get more then one person in infopath, by userPicker How could I get more then one user in Infopath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have enabled `Allow multiple selections:` to `Yes` in the specific people picker column, either from SharePoint or Infopath.

In infoPath, right click the control and go to properties and the tab `General` and check `Allow multiple selections`.

Comment: Glad you found it. :)

Comment: And You told me :)